# Is it possible to disable the swipe functionality when the image is zoomed?

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I am using `angular2-useful-swiper` wrapper for `iDangerous Swiper` for a project and I need to disable the swiping functionality when the image is zoomed.

In [Swiper Api](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#controller) there is nothing about this, so the question: is it possible?

Comment: Looks to me as if you would have to fork it, and add functionality

Answer (score 1):

as a work-around, you could subscribe to swiper's 'zoomChange' event and based on the scale (one of 3 args of it) update the `mySwiper.allowTouchMove` to `false`.
that worked for me in the Vue app.

my use-case

```
yourCallbackToEvent(scale) {
  yourSwiper.allowTouchMove = scale === 1;
};
```